Artifact when slow scroll with react-virtuoso and dynamic list
I am making a messaging system And to make the list more fluid I use react-virtuoso, This one works well the only problem I have, and which is still annoying, is that when I scroll slowly to go up the list of elements it creates visual artifacts. When I put static element heights I do not have this problem so it is when the elements appear in the DOM, and especially the images, that the problem occurs.
This is the code:
<div className="my-conversation__container">
                            <div className="my-conversation__background">
                                <div className="my-conversation__message-list__message" aria-label="Message de la conversation">
                                    <Virtuoso
                                        key={conversationIdState}
                                        style={{ height: '100%', scrollbarWidth: 'none' }}
                                        data={filteredMessages}
                                        totalCount={filteredMessages.length}
                                        overscan={100}
                                        increaseViewportBy={{ top: 500, bottom: 500 }}
                                        components={{ Footer: () => <div style={{ height: '0.5rem' }} /> }}
                                        initialTopMostItemIndex={filteredMessages.length - 1}
                                        itemContent={(index, message) => (
                                            <div
                                                className={`my-conversation__message-list__message__detail ${message.user_id === id ? 'me' : ''}`}
                                                key={index}
                                                aria-label={`Message de ${message.user_id === id ? 'vous' : 'l\'autre utilisateur'}`}
                                            >
                                                <motion.div
                                                    className={`content ${message.user_id === id ? 'me' : ''}`}
                                                    initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.9 }}
                                                    animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
                                                    exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.9, transition: { duration: 0.1, type: 'tween' } }}
                                                    transition={{ duration: 0.3, type: 'tween' }}
                                                >
                                                    {message.media[0].url && (
                                                        <div className="my-conversation__message-list__message__detail__image-container">
                                                            <div className={`map ${message.content ? 'message' : ''}`}>
                                                                {message.media?.map((media, index) => (
                                                                    media ? (
                                                                        media.name.endsWith('.pdf') ? (
                                                                            <a
                                                                                className="a-pdf"
                                                                                href={media.url}
                                                                                key={media.id}
                                                                                download={media.name}
                                                                                target="_blank"
                                                                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                                                                onClick={(event) => { event.stopPropagation(); }}
                                                                                aria-label={`Télécharger le fichier PDF ${media.name}`}
                                                                            >
                                                                                <img
                                                                                    className={`my-conversation__message-list__message__detail__image-pdf ${message.media.length === 1 ? 'single' : 'multiple'}`}
                                                                                    src={pdfLogo}
                                                                                    alt={media.name}
                                                                                />
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        ) : (
                                                                            <img
                                                                                className={`my-conversation__message-list__message__detail__image ${message.media.length === 1 ? 'single' : 'multiple'}`}
                                                                                key={media.id}
                                                                                src={media.thumbnail} // Display thumbnail initially
                                                                                data-src={media.url}
                                                                                loading="lazy"
                                                                                onLoad={(event) => {
                                                                                    // Swap thumbnail with actual image when loaded
                                                                                    if (event.currentTarget.dataset.src) {
                                                                                        event.currentTarget.src = event.currentTarget.dataset.src;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }}
                                                                                onClick={(event) => {
                                                                                    const imageUrls = message.media?.map((m) => m.url) || [];
                                                                                    setHasManyImages(false),
                                                                                        openModal(imageUrls, index),
                                                                                        imageUrls.length > 1 && setHasManyImages(true);
                                                                                    event.stopPropagation();
                                                                                }}
                                                                    
                                                                                alt={media.name}
                                                                                onError={(event) => {
                                                                                    event.currentTarget.src = noPicture;
                                                                                }}
                                                                            />
                                                                        )

                                                                    ) : null
                                                                ))
                                                                }
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    )}
                                                    {index}
                                                    {message.content && (
                                                        <div className="my-conversation__message-list__message__detail__texte">{message.content}</div>
                                                    )}
                                                </motion.div>
                                                <motion.time
                                                    className="my-conversation__message-list__message__detail__date"
                                                    style={{ overflow: 'scroll' }}
                                                    initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.9 }}
                                                    animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
                                                    exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.9, transition: { duration: 0.1, type: 'tween' } }}
                                                    transition={{ duration: 0.3, type: 'tween' }}
                                                    dateTime={new Date(Number(message.created_at)).toISOString()}
                                                >
                                                    {formatMessageDate(message.created_at)}
                                                </motion.time>
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                        }

                                        followOutput={(isAtBottom) => isAtBottom}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


I tried to put the thumbnails in order to be able to display the image formats more quickly, But it still does not work, I cannot use a placeholder for the scroll because it is not during a fast scroll but during a slow scroll that this happens.
